# How to interact iphone with PHP/MySQl web server

Tags: iphone-web-app

I want to interact my Iphone application with a php website having MySQL database.

What basically I want is to  fetch data from MySQL database and display it in my IPhone application and after doing some processing in IPhone I want to retrun some information to PHP website in form of XML.

Can any one help me in doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Gaurav

Answer (score 2):

the iphone have safari and that safari version has Ajax feature, so the basic answer you can do it like any other webpage development.

after if you want to implement a native app that's a different story.

I suppose you have to code a webservice (PHP) to consume data. I can imagine it's not really difficult to do HTTP request using the iphone SDK.